# Talend CSV File

Tags: database, csv, talend

I'm trying to generate a csv file using Talend, 
So I have a connection component, a request component and a tfileoutputDelimited component. 
And the request component is connected to the output component.
It creates a csv file in my folder but there are a lot of characters which are not written correctly in the csv file.

So what encoding should I use to get exactly the characters of the database (it's an sql server database) ? Utf-8 ?

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: What encoding does the database use?

Comment: when I export manually the  a sql view in csv , I got an utf8-bom file